# How to change the default compilation command/shortcut in GNU Emacs-AUCTeX?

Tags: emacs, compilation, latex, command, auctex

In GNU Emacs with AUCTeX enabled, C-C C-C is the default shortcut for running latex over the active buffer. How can I change this to also run dvips after the dvi output is generated by latex? Can I define a new shortcut, say C-C C-D, and assign it to the foregoing operation?

Answer (score 1):

```
M-x describe-key <RET> C-c C-c
C-h k C-c C-c
```

will each give you the function name that is called for compile. Then you can rebind as follows in your .emacs:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-d") '<function name>)
```

This isn't fully general, as I'm not fully familiar with the innards of AUCTeX. Typically there is some type of mode hook to run (keeps you from rebinding a global).

Here's an example adapted from http://emacswiki.org/emacs/AUCTeX

```
 (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
              '(lambda ()
                 (local-set-key "<key>" '<function name>)))
```

As to your question about running dvips, you would define your own function and do a keybinding. in a similar manner as above.